# Identifying alert sounds

Tags: audio, alert

I've been hearing this unfamiliar "alert" sound – kind of like a badly played guitar string slapping against the frets. After the sound occurs I don't see any new badges or any other indications that something happened…

I've been though all of the stock sounds in System Preferences > Sounds > Sound Effects and while Basso sounds close (hard to say for sure since I can't make the sound happen on demand) I don't think it is the one.

So the question, in three parts:

1. Is there any way to identify the source of alerts?
2. If I knew the name of the sound, would that help? (Should I / could I go looking for places where Basso is used?
3. Can "non-stock" sounds be used for alerts?

I'm running the 10.12.3 beta on a Mid-2014 MBP.

Comment: Check [& listen to] System prefs > Sound > Sound Effects. Is it 'Basso' ?

Comment: I don't think it is Basso, it comes close, but this sound is "harsher" - that was a great suggestion and I went through all of the sounds, none of them matched the sound that I remember, but i can't produce it on demand :-(

Comment: As best I've been able to figure at this point the sound seems most closely related to viewing Stack Exchange sites, maybe specifically their chat rooms, I've been doing that in Safari. But it still doesn't seem to correlate with anything…

Comment: Then we have a winner...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SE Chat plays a twanged rubber band sound when someone pings you with @yourName in a room you have open.

You can change that pref by clicking the speaker icon at the top of the chat room.

[image]

Comment: Hahaha - yup, for sure. I've 12 to a window & 4 windows open right now ;)

Comment: Going to have to listen to it more carefully and see if I can hear a rubber band in it. Sounded to me like a guitar string pulled up and allowed to snap back down onto the frets while you're muting it with a finger, but that might just be my lack of imagination :-)